# Windows 7 laptop left arrow key is constanty held downl

Tags: windows-7, laptop

Sorry for anything mispelled in this my laptop acts like the left arrow key is contsantl being pressed down when it's not i tried holding it down and other ways to fix it but nothing s helping also when i try to cick it normally it wont workl liy (Also i cant replace my keyboard) is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Still looking for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First, try to pry the key up VERY GENTLY. Use a paperclip, but if you pop the key off it may just snap back on, but don't push it too much. 2nd, does your laptop have any USB ports, you should be able to plug in a full size keyboard and it will be hot, no config needed.

Good Luck.
Dyn0